# ruby on rails average per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Referencing this post:

[ruby on rails average per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272888/ruby-on-rails-average-per-day)

I'm getting the average per day, which works fine. Until now that the month switched over...

I have this code

```
score = (7.days.ago.to_date.to_s(:db)..Date.today.tomorrow.to_s(:db)).map{|dt| [dt, ave_score[dt] || 0]}
```

Which works, but now that the month switches over, it comes back with dates that don't exist, like 2009-08-32 to 2009-08-99 and 2009-09-00. All in the array. How can I delete dates that don't actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it so if anybody else would like to add something go for it:

```
arr_count = 0
length = score.length
while arr_count < length
   begin
      score[arr_count][0].to_date  
      arr_count = arr_count + 1
   rescue
     @score.delete_at(arr_count)
     length = length - 1
   end
end
```

Comment: It probably wasn't tried. People only use things if it was what they wanted to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting to make the call to `to_s`:

```
score = (7.days.ago.to_date..Date.today.tomorrow).map{ |dt| d = dt.to_s(:db); [d, ave_score[d] || 0] }
```